# Bootstrap Gallery Search / Filter Function

Tags: filtering, bootstrap-5, keyword, image-gallery

I have created a Bootstrap Gallery and have added a search / filter based on some code I found here: https://www.christosgeo.com/2022/01/26/how-to-filter-bootstrap-gallery/

It works to a degree but I need help expanding the search / filter function.

For example, if I add the following keywords to a gallery item - landscape, mountain, sea, waves, one can enter any of them individually into the filter search and it works fine. If however one enters more than one word, it has to be in the order the keywords have been added eg. if I enter landscape, mountain it works fine, if however I enter landscape, sea no items are filtered.

So basically I need to be able to enter keywords in any order and the search / filter must display all items with the same keyword, regardless of order.

Below is the portion of the code that performs the filter / search function

```
<script>
        var searchFilter = () => {
            const input = document.querySelector(".form-control");
            const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
            console.log(cards[1])
            let filter = input.value
            for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
                let title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body");
                if (title.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                    cards[i].classList.remove("d-none")
                } else {
                    cards[i].classList.add("d-none")
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

I hope the above makes sense? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what happened to the above code!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember questions should be relevant and helpful to future reasons. Therefore, don't link to external websites that will break or change in time and become useless to future readers.

Comment: What is the best way then to reference external code?

Comment: You should not reference external code. If your code is too big to include in a question, the usual recommendation is to reduce it to a [mre].

Comment: Create a MVE, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask